# Querying multiple related tables with join to generate single table using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a web app which manages the inventory system and selling books and items. I want to generate the monthly based report on how many books where sold and ordered to Inventory in given period of time. In order to do this I have to join several tables. Here are my tables:
- `Book` Table

```
class Book(ResourceMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(85))
    stock_amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, server_default='0')

    #Foreign Key
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id',
                                                    onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                    ondelete='CASCADE'),
                        index=True, nullable=False)
```

- Category Table

```
class Category(ResourceMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String(85))
    isbn1 = db.Column(db.String(13))
    isbn2 = db.Column(db.String(13))
    total_stock_amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    selling_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    bank_transfer_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    unit_cost = db.Column(db.Float)
    author = db.Column(db.String(100))


    ordered = db.Column('is_ordered', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')

    #Association Proxies

    orders = association_proxy('book_orders', 'order')
    stores = association_proxy('book_store', 'store')

    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('suppliers.id',
                                                    onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                    ondelete='CASCADE'),
                        index=True, nullable=False)

    #Relationship with Books

    books = db.relationship(Book, backref=db.backref('book_category'), innerjoin=True)
```

- `BookStore` table which inherits from `Category` table

```
class BookStore(ResourceMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'book_store'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'))
    isbn1 = db.Column(db.String)
    isbn2 = db.Column(db.String)
    book_amount = db.Column(db.Integer)



    #Bidirectional attribute/collection of 'category'/'book_store'

    category = db.relationship('Category', backref = db.backref('book_store', cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
                            lazy='joined', innerjoin=True,
                            order_by='Category.category_name')


    bookstore_cart = db.relationship('StoreCart', backref='book_store_cart', passive_deletes=True)

    book_purchases = association_proxy('book_orders', 'customer_purchases')

    #Reference to the 'Store' object

    store = db.relationship('Store')
```

- `CustomerPurchase` table which is inherits from `BookStore`

```
class CustomerPurchase(ResourceMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'customer_purchase'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    book_store_category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book_store.id'))
    customer_order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer_orders.id'))

    book_title = db.Column(db.Text)
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Float) 
    total_price = db.Column(db.Float)

    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id',
                                                    onupdate='CASCADE',
                                                    ondelete='CASCADE'),
                        index=True)

    #Bidirectional attribute/collection of 'bookstore'/'customer purchase'

    book_purchase = db.relationship('BookStore', backref = db.backref('customer_purchases', cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
                            lazy='joined', innerjoin=True,
                            order_by='BookStore.isbn1')

    #Bidirectional attribute/collection of 'store'/'purchase'

    customer_order = db.relationship('CustomerOrders')
```

Let me explain you the working principle. So in order to sell books user has to transfer `Category` to the `BookStore` and then s/he can sell it. Sales are stored in `CustomerPurchase` table. If books in inventory are finished, then the User has to order books from supplier and put it in inventory, the date of the input to the inventory is captured to generate report in future.

My desired report table should include these columns

```
   book_title | unit_cost | amount_in_stock | revenue | amount_ordered | total_price_of_ordered_books | amount_sold | revenue | amount_left | total_price_of_amount_left |
```

My query is:

```
bp = db.session.query(CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id, BookStore.category, func.sum(CustomerPurchase.quantity).label('quantity'))\
     .filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on >= start_date)\
     .filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on <= end_date)\
     .group_by(CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id, BookStore.id, Category.id)\
     .subquery()


cp = db.session.query(BookStore, bp.c.quantity)\
                     .join(bp, BookStore.category_id == bp.c.book_store_category_id)\
                     .distinct(bp.c.book_store_category_id)\
                     .order_by(bp.c.book_store_category_id)\
                     .all()
```

It outputs the `CustomerPurchase` and `BookStore` table but doesn't go beyond it for example I cannot go down `CustomerPurchase.book_purchase.category.books.stock_amount` or `BookStore.category.books.stock_amount`

When I want to access CustomerPurchase.book_purchase it throws me an error
`UndefinedError: 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result object' has no attribute 'book_purchase'`

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of research and collaboration I managed to solve the problem:

Now it outputs all the desired columns and returns even though a column is NULL:

```
my_query = db.session.query(CustomerPurchase.book_title, Category.unit_cost, Category.total_stock_amount, BookStore.book_amount,
                    func.sum(CustomerPurchase.quantity).label('quantity'),
                    func.sum(Book.stock_amount).label('book_stock_amount'))\
                    .join(BookStore)\
                    .join(Category)\
                    .outerjoin(Book)\
                    .filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on >= report.start_date.date())\
                    .filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on <= report.end_date.date())\
                    .group_by(CustomerPurchase.book_title,
                            Category.unit_cost, Category.total_stock_amount,
                            BookStore.book_amount).all()
```

As simple as that! Basically I have to cherry pick every column that I want to display. Also I was concerned about **NULL** return value of Book.stock_amount but after I used `outerjoin` on `Book` table I managed to pull out all the data I needed for my report.

I hope it will help for some people out there! :)